# why Query not return any result

Tags: sql

I use the following code but the it doesnot return any thing,

```
declare @test varchar(50)  ;

declare @result varchar(10)  ;

set @result = 'A';

IF(@test = 'A')
BegIN
select count(*) from users where u_id = 15
END

else if (@test == 'B')
BEGIN

END
```

the query return results `select count(*) from users where u_id = 15` 
any idea how to solve that

Best regards

Comment: You're not setting `@test` to any value...... so none of your `if (@test == ....) ` will ever execute.....

Comment: where is @test initialization?

Comment: where is @test initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this first?

```
declare @test varchar(50)  ;

declare @result varchar(10)  ;

SET @test = 'A';

IF (@test = 'A')
    BEGIN
        select count(*) from users where u_id = 15
    END
ELSE IF (@test = 'B')
    BEGIN

    END
```

Answer (score -1):

you tried to set value to @test within the if condition.

Try this

```
IF(@test == 'A')
BegIN
select count(*) from users where u_id = 15
END
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!